# How to redirect from https to http in a specific nginx location block for a URL

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect, proxypass

this question does not duplicate of this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/283734/how-to-redirect-every-https-request-to-http-in-nginx)

My application is web based and developed in django, deployed through UWSGI application server with nginx as a reverse proxy. The task is to redirect from **https** to **http** for a specific URL, but this sound does not simpler to me as I tried to cope up with following nginx configuration are as:

The default proxy config are as:

```
proxy_redirect      off;
proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server  $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
```

The location block where Issue happened are as:

```
    location ~ /target\.xml$ {
        if ($scheme = https) {
           return 302 http://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }
```

The url which we need to redirect are as:

```
**https://test-server.com/api/stage/7uibsiub3jbh3v3h/target.xml**
```

Here if a url contains target.xml and is on https scheme then it should be redirect to http but we were receiving **redirect loop** in block due to missing **if condition** in location. As soon as we added if condition to check the scheme the nginx gave us **`404 Not Found`** error. I had double cross check with nginx documentation which told me to not go for if condition as it could be evil most of the times so I stick with location but I am unable to debug it more.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That location block processes both the `http` and `https` request for `target.xml`. The `https` request is redirected to `http`. But how is the `http` request processed? Is it a file or should it be sent to a `proxy_pass`? The `location` does not contain anything to process the `http` version of the request.

Comment: The root location of api is `location ~ ^/(admin|api/) {
    client_max_body_size 200M;
    uwsgi_pass django;
    include uwsgi_params;
}`.  Where it'll be redirected to and handled by uwsgi application server through django upstream. So this location will invoke whenever a url contains api arrives.

Comment: The preferred solution would be to split the `server` block into two `server` blocks, one for `http` and one for `https`. But an interim solution would be to add the `uwsgi` statements to your new `location` block.

Comment: The server is on aws elastic load balancer and configured SSL from Interface. So we cannot override it through block, I gave a try but that does not work. Regarding the interim solution still we have to pass the http scheme with uwsgi, I am figuring out it